# TTy Port Sharing - Access the same port by two different process simultaneously.Port Sharing - Raspberry

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, serial-port, connection-sharing

I need read the Port `/dev/ttyACM0` by two different process simultaneously. Its possible Share this port as a way to processes access this port, or split in two another ports? Something like this :

```
                  ___/dev/ttyPort1
  /dev/ttyACM0 --/
                 \___/dev/ttyPort2
```

I tryed install a socat and use `socat /dev/ttyPort1 /dev/ttyACM0`. this worked partially. With socat I got the new port as a mirror of the ttyACM0, but when I connect to read this ports simultaneously, the information received just appears in ttyACM0 or ttyPort1, never in both at the same time, and I need the same information for 2 process at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

If your programs are willing to read from a fifo rather than a tty, and you are just reading and not writing then you can use `tee` and two fifos:

```
mkfifo fifo1 fifo2
tee </dev/ttyS0 fifo1 >fifo2 &
```

You can now open `fifo1` and `fifo2` and read the same data from each.
If you really need a tty, then you could add a `socat` to read each fifo and connect it to a pty:

```
socat -u GOPEN:fifo1 pty,link=$HOME/ttyPort1,raw,echo=0 &
socat -u GOPEN:fifo2 pty,link=$HOME/ttyPort2,raw,echo=0 &
```

Read `$HOME/ttyPort1` and `$HOME/ttyPort2`.

Comment: I saw a post with this commands, but I tried it and it does not work

Comment: That is not enough information to be useful. Update **your original post** with the actual commands you tried and what observations you made, what errors you saw. Did you use the fifo version or the fifo and socat version? Explain in your original post what your programs are doing. Do they read and write? Do they do ioctls to set the speed and echo and so on?